# Can I avoid setting up a proxy for GeoServer, Apache?

Tags: geoserver, proxy, apache

I'm using Apache (port 80) and GeoServer (port 8080) on Windows 7. I guess I need to set up a proxy if I want to use WFS, since they're on different ports.

My kind of silly question is, can I avoid it? If I re-set my website on GeoServer's www file, is everything going to work fine? Does GeoServer share the same characteristics with Apache?

If GeoServer's www file is a bad idea can you please help me set up a proxy? I never done it before, so if you have a link with an analytical tutorial, it would be great...

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? Is this an already-in-production site, or can you change URLs without much trouble? Are you familiar with Apache configuration?

Comment: The whole system is on my laptop, still localhosts.I'm not so experienced with Apache config...

Comment: You can avoid using Apache HTTP server, and just run the Java server (Tomcat/Jetty).  You can run these on port 80 if required, what's you requirement for Apache HTTP server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your Apache is on port 80 and your Geoserver is on the same machine on port 8080.

I would suggest that you set up a reverse proxy on your Apache server. On my server I have set up Apache to resolve http://example.com/geoserver to  http://example.com:8080/

That way I can just use the wms link as http://example.com/geoserver/wms & I don't need to use a proxy.cgi file.

You can see [this Post](http://rk.tiddlyspace.com/Apache%20Reverse%20Proxy%20for%20Geoserver%20on%20Windows) on how to set Apache to route to another port using Virtual Hosts.

Comment: @ Devdatta I added to the Apache's httpd.conf file these lines 
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so

LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

and at the end these

ProxyPass /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver
   ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://localhost:8080/geoserver

and I can now acceess geoserver's admin console through 80 port (using http://localhost/geoserver/web/ instead of http://localhost:8080/geoserver/web/).

I guess proxy is ok now?

Comment: @ Devdatta What about this line? OpenLayers.ProxyHost = '/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url='; Says I have to change the URL to point to my ProxyHost...But I did not add a proxy.cgi file at all...

Comment: You don't need that line at all. SInce now your geoserver is on the same domain as your appliation (i.e you are accessing your wms service as http://domain/geoserver/wms) you will not run into the crossdomain limitation

Answer (score 1):

Almost any tool that you want to use with Apache or Geoserver will accept a port number as part of the URL. So for something like openlayers, a simple WFS example is shown at http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wfs-filter.html

If you look at the source of that, you'll see a part that looks like:

```
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                url:  "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
                featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
            }),
```

For you, that is going to be something like:

```
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                url:  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                featureType: "tasmania_roads",
                featureNS: "http://www.openplans.org/topp"
            }),
```

(where the bit after localhost:8080 depends on how you set up your geoserver, but should be fine if `http://localhost:8080/geoserver` brings up the admin console, as shown in http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/windows/installer.html)

With that information, you should be able to avoid setting up a reverse proxy on Apache.

Comment: @ Brad What do you mean by "where the bit after localhost:8080 depends on how you set up your geoserver"? I thought that the url that I set was OK. And I need a proxy anyway because of the different ports. That's interesting (and I'm a rookie as you can see). Pls explain

Comment: Sorry: its hard for me to understand how you set up your GeoServer instance, and I don't understand what you do and don't know. GeoServer is very flexible, so there are some possibilities here. I'll expand the words above.

Comment: No, it's my fault, I am sorry, let me rephrase. How can I check if the url I gave in WFS protocol, is valid?

Comment: You can do the procedure I put above (seeing if the management console comes up). To check WFS in particular, you can add "?request=getcapabilities" to the end of the URL, and check if that works in a browser or with curl or some other command line tool, (returning an XML file). So if http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=getcapabilities works, it is the right URL.

Comment: So, http://localhost:8080/geoserver actually does bring  the admin console, but when I do a getcapabilities request, I get this on Chrome's console XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?request=getcapabilities. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Maybe you need a less-sophisticated browser (perhaps firefox). Anyway, if the admin console works, everything should be fine.